# File Version Custom Fields

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to use the sharepoint rest api to get the file version history but also the custom fields on those versions. I tried to do expand on ListItemAllFields, FieldValuesAsText and ListItemAllFields/FieldValuesAsText but no luck. I keep getting the same system attributes. does anyone know if its possible to access version history fields? if yes  then how to do it?
Thanks